# The Maximum Height A Block Can Climb On A Ramp

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

In a similar setup, (all surfaces are smooth) I was asked to calculate the maximum height the block can climb, I used the principles of energy and momentum conservation but when my teacher applied the momentum conservation, he took the horizontal velocity of both the blocks same.

Why is it that when the block attains the maxima in it’s height , their horizontal velocities become the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you may think in the frame which the block $M$ is fixed. The block $m$ is moving up while surffering gravitational force, $- m g \hat{y}$, and the inertial force from the acceleration frame of $M$, $- m a_M \hat{x}$.

Though, the forces become a little complicated, but eventually, the block $m$ will be tired of climbing, then stop for a short rest. It will starting moving backward (and getting lower) in the next moment. Behold, at this highest posiiton, in this very moment, $m$ is stationery at the $M$ frame. What is that meaning  "stationery"? No doubts, they are moving together with a same velocity.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track since you think of using conservaion of energy and momentum. Velocity of the block of mass $m$ and and ramp $M$ are taken the same in horizontal direction since the system moves together. Picture-wise, it's like in the inelastic collisions, when two masses move together with the same velocity after the collision.